# Android: Creating a high quality thumbnail image

Tags: java, android, image, scale

I have some difficulties creating a high quality thumbnail for my captured images. I understand that there are many snippet codes and tutorials in the web to create a thumbnail. I tried them and my problem is I can't produce a high quality thumbnail image. The output is always pixelated. Any suggestion ,library or links guys? thanks in advance.

[I tried this one](http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-create-thumbnail-image-in.html) but its low quality also.

```
 public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int wantedWidth, int wantedHeight) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(wantedWidth, wantedHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        m.setScale((float) wantedWidth / bitmap.getWidth(), (float) wantedHeight / bitmap.getHeight());

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, new Paint());

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Which language version and which platform are you developing on? Are you developing web application that serves content to an android browser?

Comment: Im using java in android. I have this native android application with a custom camera and I want to create a thumbnail of my captured image.

Comment: Show us some code of what you tried. I could define nice thumbnails using only android apis.

Comment: @Snicolas , I post some codes. kindly check. :)

Comment: You should have a look at this : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. And this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19486896/693752

Answer (score 0):

Use [RapidDecoder](https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder) library. It is simple as follow:

```
import rapid.decoder.BitmapDecoder;
...
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapDecoder.from(getResources(), R.drawable.image)
                             .scale(width, height)
                             .useBuiltInDecoder(true)
                             .decode();
```

Don't forget to use builtin decoders if you want to scale down less than 50% and a HQ result.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this,

```
Bitmap src = Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), ContentUris.parseId(sourceUri), Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, options);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
Bitmap ThumbImage =ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath),THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

This Utility is available from API_LEVEl 8. [Source]