# Android: OutOfMemoryError to load a imageResource

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, drawable

I've caught a code example to pinch and zoom an image. The works ok. The problem is when I implement this code in my app. I have an OutOfMemoryError here:

**view.setImageResource (R.drawable.planometro);**

To solve this problem I found this code:

```
public Drawable getAssetImage (String filename) throws IOException {

    AssetManager assets = getResources () getAssets ().; 
    InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream ((assets.open ("drawable /" + filename +)) "png."); 
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (buffer); 
    return new BitmapDrawable (getResources (), bitmap); 
 }
```

The problem is that this code is to return an int, not a drawable. How I can fix my error?

Thanks

Comment: scaled down your Bitmap

Comment: May be your image has a high resolution

Comment: i think you only get this error (OutOfMemoryError) on your emulator, so just test it on a real phone.

Comment: go to Official Documentation  [http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) They explain everything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485680/how-to-scale-an-image-down-in-android check this link

Comment: The image is very big. And i test in my phone.

Comment: That's why you got out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
try {
   Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.matches_placeholder_upcoming2x)).getBitmap();
   Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(),bitmap);
   liveMatchHeaderContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);    

} catch (OutOfMemoryError E) {
    E.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: if I do a backgroundDrawable, my app does not work because I want to pinch image to zoom

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, try it out:

```
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//          Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what project build target api do you use?