# Going crazy with scaleType

Tags: android, android-layout

I have images that could be either 300x600px or 600x300px. I want them to be displayed in a box of 50dp. So the image would be 25dp x 50dp or 50x25dp depending on its ratio

I have tried various things and I am going crazy

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

or

(this doesn't crop anything...)

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image"/>
```

But none work and it seems that whatever value I put in `scaleType` is ignored

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485680/how-to-scale-an-image-down-in-android) works

Comment: so you can't do this through xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `scaleType="fitCenter"` (if you want to upscale small images) or `scaleType="centerInside"` (otherwise).

Disable `adjustViewBounds`.